# How to add a contact by API?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any class about the operation of the contact?

how to add a contact with API like the way in windows mobile?

SaveEmailAddressTask and SavePhoneNumberTask are not useful.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_wincontacts/

Answer (score 1):

The only APIs that the framework provides (at the moment at least) are the two tasks that you have already identified. To be honest, I wouldn't be surprised if it stays that way, too, in order to prevent malicious applications from littering the user's contacts.

Comment: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/104644-allow-deny-os-apps-access-contacts-windows-10-a.html